# About multiplicity of a root of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

I am reading "A Course in Analysis 1" by Kazuo Matsuzaka.

In this book, the author wrote the following fact without a proof:

> A polynomial $f(x)$ is divisible by $(x-a)^k$ but is not divisible by $(x-a)^{k+1}$ iff there is a polynomial $g(x)$ such that $f(x) = (x-a)^k g(x)$ and $g(a) \neq 0$.

A polynomial has the unique factorization. If I use this fact, it is easy to prove the above fact.

But in this book, the author didn't write about the unique factorization of a polynomial.

My attempt is here:

> Suppose that a polynomial $f(x)$ is divisible by $(x-a)^k$ but is not divisible by $(x-a)^{k+1}$.
>   Then, there is a polynomial $g(x)$ such that $f(x) = (x-a)^k g(x)$.
>   If $g(a) = 0$, then, there is a polynomial $h(x)$ such that $g(x) = (x-a) h(x)$.
>   So, $f(x) = (x-a)^k (x-a) h(x) = (x-a)^{k+1} h(x)$.
>   So, $f(x)$ is divisible by $(x-a)^{k+1}$.
>   This is a contradiciton.
>   I cannot prove the converse.

Comment: Do you know that a non-constant polynomial cannot have infinitely many roots? This is weaker than unique factorisation, and can be proven by real analysis (Rolle theoremm).

Comment: Note that in that case $$(x-a)^{k+1} h(x) = (x-a)^k g(x)$$ implies that $(x-a)h(x)-g(x)$ is zero for each $x \neq a$ therefore $(x-a)h(x)-g(x)$ is the zero polynomial.

Comment: Last but not least, to cancel $(X-a)^k$ you don't need to know that $\mathbb R[X]$ is an UFD, you only need to know that it is an integral domain. Which again follows trivially from knowing that a non-zero polynomial cannot have infinitely many roots.

Comment: Thank you very much @N.S.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f(x)=(x-a)^kg(x)$, $g(a)\neq 0$ and $f(x)=(x-a)^{k+1}h(x)=(x-a)^kg(x)$, this implies that $g(x)=(x-a)h(x)$ and $g(a)=0$ contradiction.

Comment: How can I prove that $(x-a)^{k+1} h(x) = (x-a)^k g(x)$ implies $g(x) = (x-a) h(x)$?

Comment: $(x-a)^k((x-a)h(x)-g(x))=0$